# How to have LoadRunner also measure cpu and memory usage of a remote Windows web server?

Tags: testing, performance-testing, loadrunner

Now I am running LoadRunner Community (V12.56) on my PC to test the performance of a web application hosted in IIS of a remote Windows web server. LR did generate performance report about the web application. But it seems that LR can't get any data about cpu and memory usage of the web server.

Must I install some agent of LR on the remote web server at first in order to collect these data?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See LR documentation on monitoring.  LR and SiteScope both take advantage of the PerfMon interface to collect metrics from the base Windows OS and any services running on top of Windows which create PerfMon counters.  This is highly dependent upon the credentials that you use to connect to the host as to whether you can pull the stats.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to install anything if you have permissions on that machine.
In the Controller application, go to the Run tab (on the bottom).
In the Avaliable Graphs section (on the left) scroll down to Web Server Resource Graphs, then select MS IIS.
When the graph appears, right-click it and select Add Measurements. A dialog will open that will allow you to select which measurements you want to see.

If this is not enough, go to System Resource Graphs, there you have Windows Resources graph. Follow the same steps as for the previous graph.

(You can do this before running the test)

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Perfmon on your LoadRunner host.  Connect to the remote windows host you are looking to collect data from.  If you can see it here, then you can collect it in the Controller.   The controller relies upon the same PerfMon remote interface and the existing credentials to gain access to the metrics.

If you cannot see any metrics, then you need to have your ID provided with credentials for that host.  If this is in a different domain, then there is a bit of a hack you can do which works around this.

1. Connect to a file service on the remote windows host using a local machine credential which has access to the perfmon metrics.
2. When you connect to the Windows host again using performance manager or controller the security token is usually inherited from the already connected windows file service instead of using your default signed in credentials.  Or, at least it has been the case in the past.  I am leaving a bit of wiggle room in case Microsoft has closed this as a security hole.